# Calling GLPK from C++ while using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, glpk

I am developing part of my R package in C++ using Rcpp and I need to use a Linear Programming Solver.

After comparing some benchmarks using the solvers implementation into R (lpSolveAPI, Rglpk, Rsymphony and so on) I have decided to use GLPK. However, I have found no good way to use it in my C++ code developing under Windows.

Simply put, there is no simple way to just install GLPK and call it using something like

```
#include <glpk.h>
```

and I have found no implementations in R packages so that I can use a shortcut using Rcpp attributes like

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(package)]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you are aware of the [`Rglpk` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rglpk/) and its predecessor [`glpk`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glpk/). Often in these cases, it's helpful to stand on the shoulders of those that came before us. Having said that, we gleam from the package sources the following:

1. The [source of `Rglpk`](https://github.com/cran/Rglpk) requires a pre-existing system install, does not enable linking, and is specific to Linux.
2. The [source of `glpk`](https://github.com/cran/glpk) installs the library headers directly in R and it seems to also provide [direct wrappers](https://github.com/cran/glpk/blob/master/src/R_lpx.c) into the library.

Given the current implementations and your requirements, you would basically have to create an `RcppGLPK` package. This is primarily because no one really has a solution for what you need. I would highly suggest that you look at how `RcppGSL` is structured.